# Simplifying Rust macro rules for nested looping

Tags: macros, rust

I have a simple macro with three very similar rules:

```
macro_rules! c {

($exp:expr, for $i:ident in $iter:expr) => (
    {
        let mut r = vec![];
        for $i in $iter {
            r.push($exp);
        }
        r
    }
);

($exp:expr, for $i:ident in $iter:expr, for $i2:ident in $iter2:expr) => (
    {
        let mut r = vec![];
        for $i2 in $iter2 {
            for $i in $iter {
                r.push($exp);
            }
        }
        r
    }
);

($exp:expr, for $i:ident in $iter:expr, for $i2:ident in $iter2:expr, for $i3:ident in $iter3:expr) => (
    {
        let mut r = vec![];
        for $i in $iter {
            for $i2 in $iter2 {
                for $i3 in $iter3 {
                    r.push($exp);
                }
            }
        }
        r
    }
);

}
```

Each rule differs from the others by the number of `for $i:ident in $iter:exp` patterns being matched. The logic is similarly the same.

Is there a way to simplify these rules into one using repetition patterns such as `$(...)*` or `$(...)+` and still be able to express the nested looping in the macro logic?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=35269df7238544214582f713d3b85ede&version=stable)

Comment: Would you accept an answer that used https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.6/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product ?

Comment: I would prefer a solution reliant on the std lib only. But knowing  how itertools can achieve this would be beneficial too. Maybe a playground link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [recursive TT (token tree) munching macro](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html):

```
macro_rules! c {
    (@loop $v:ident, $exp:expr, for $i:ident in $iter:expr) => (
        for $i in $iter {
            $v.push($exp);
        }
    );

    (@loop $v:ident, $exp:expr, for $i:ident in $iter:expr, $($tail:tt)*) => (
        for $i in $iter {
            c!(@loop $v, $exp, $($tail)*);
        }
    );

    ($exp:expr, $(for $i:ident in $iter:expr),*) => (
        {
            let mut r = vec![];
            c!(@loop r, $exp, $(for $i in $iter),*);
            r
        }
    );
}
```

The rules labelled with `@loop` do all the work.

A TT munching recursive macro is very similar to a recursive function. At every invocation, it processes (munches) only a portion of the input, generates intermediate output, and sends the remaining "unmunched" input tail to another macro invocation. Eventually, the input is small enough to not require any more macro invocations and reaches the base case at which the recursion is terminated.

Here, the recursive `@loop` rule captures a *single* token tree matching to `for $i:ident in $iter:expr`, and stores the remaining input (other such `for $i in $iter` expressions) in a `$($tail:tt)*`. The macro rule then generates the loop for the captured `for $i in $iter` expression and generates the loop body by invoking the *same* rule with the unmunched input (`$($tail)*`).

Eventually, `$($tail)*` contains only *one* token tree that can be matched to `for $i:ident in $iter:expr`. In that case, the base case `@loop` rule is called, generating the innermost loop which pushes the expression onto the `Vec`.

This macro should work for an arbitrary number of `for $i in $iter` expressions as long as it stays within the macro recursion limit. If you do find yourself up against the recursion limit, the number of recursive invocations can be reduced by processing *two* `for $i:ident in $iter:expr` expressions at once in the recursive `@loop` rule.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4ff333720e99f78cb4bd2612046b6685&version=stable)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @EvilTak